# Why my neural network always predicts the same class?

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following neural network for binary classification. The problem is it always predicts the same class (class 1, or positive class). I tried oversampling the negative class so that the ratio of the positive is about 43% but still the model produces 1. Basically, it is not doing any training.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
input1 = Input(shape=(10,100)) #number of time steps and number of features
lstm1 = LSTM(units=10)(input1)
dense_1 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(lstm1)
dense_2 = Dense(4, activation='relu')(dense_1)
dense_3 = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(dense_2)
model = Model(inputs=[input1],outputs=[dense_3])
# compile the model
opt = Adam(lr=1e-06)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_Doc2Vec_LSTM.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]

train_history = model.fit([Data_x_train], 
          [Data_y_train], batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(Data_x_val, Data_y_val), callbacks = callbacks, verbose = 2)
```

Comment: The question is pretty vague, consider rephrasing and adding detail. I personally think this question will be better off on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *still the model produces 1*, you are using softmax with 1 neuron.

Comment: @Luke, I am wondering if there is something wrong with the network structure. What part of it is vague? What information I can possibly add?

Comment: @Frightera, but softmax output is between 0 and 1. I don't understand, would you please clarify more?

Comment: @MRM `softmax` creates a distribution with outputs which the sum of probabilities is 1. So, if you have 1 neuron, it always will be 1. Instead try using `sigmoid`, or change last layer neurons to 2 with `softmax`, and change your loss function.

Comment: @Kaveh,@Kaveh, Thank you! I tried '''categorical_crossentropy''' as my loss function and used 2 neurons for the last layer. The produced probabilities are very close two each other. You think the problem is that just features don't have much predictive power?

Comment: @MRM If your target variable is one-hot encoded such as `[0,1]` or `[1,0]` values stored in `y_train`, you can use `categorical_crossentropy`, otherwise if your target is just `0` or `1`, you should use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function.

Comment: @Kaveh, ``y_train`` is one-hot encoded

Comment: @MRM If so, Then yes, try to add more neurons in hidden layers, since 8 and 4 are relatively low for your model.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem can be your datasets, if the dataset that you used for training were unbalanced, the test error will increase. So, you need to have a balanced dataset. It contributes in improve **generalisation** and avoid **overfitting**.

Another possible solution is to do a grid search to tune the **hyperparameters** of models including batch size, epochs, activation functions, learning rate, optimizer and loss function and finds the optimum ones.